# Por que o resultado desse código vai resultar em 30?

Tags: swift

[image: Velocidade: 30]

Por que o resultado desse código vai ser 30?
Sou iniciante em Swift, mas tenho uma noção de Lógica de Programação.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa específicas que deseja saber? Já que entende a lógica, tem algum recursos da linguagem que não entende e deseja uma explicação?

Comment: Não coloque o código como imagem, pois isso impede alguém de copiar para testar ou mesmo reutilizar. Clique em [edit] e poste o código em texto mesmo, mas formatado (para saber mais, leia: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1599/formatar-c%c3%b3digo-nas-respostas-do-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

Simples como isso.

```
i = 0
```

regra if atendida

```
velocidade += i(0) * 2 OU (velocidade = velocidade(0) + 0) // Velocidade aqui é 0
```

de novo

```
i = 1
```

regra if atendida

```
velocidade += i(1) * 2 OU (velocidade = velocidade(0) + 2) // Velocidade aqui é 2
```

de novo

```
i = 2
```

regra if atendida

```
velocidade += i(2) * 2 OU velocidade = velocidade(2) + 4 // Velocidade aqui é 6
```

de novo

```
i == 3
```

Regra else atendida

```
velocidade += ++velocidade // Aqui é onde deve estar a sua dúvida a funçao ++ A esquerda primeiro incrementa um valor depois retorna ele. 

// Ou seja se velocidade aqui era 6 usando ++ você incrementa o valor dessa variavel para 7 e depois realiza a soma dos dois valores, armazendando ele na mesma variavel.

// Logo velocidade aqui é 14.
```

la vamos nos de novo

```
i == 4
```

Regra Else atendida

```
velocidade += ++velocidade

// Usando ++ a equerda velocidade passa a valer 15

// Depois Você realiza a soma velocidade(15) += velocidade(15)

// Fim do For resultado final 30
```

Ou seja ele da 30 porque realmente deveria dar 30 :), talvez você não tenha entendido como funcionam as funções.

```
postfix public func ++(inout x: Int) -> Int
prefix public func ++(inout x: Int) -> Int  

// ++variavel(10) soma 1 a variavel e depois retorna seu novo valor nesse caso 11
// variavel(10)++ retorna o seu valor nesse caso 10 depois soma 1
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

No XCode, é possível utilizar um *sandbox* do **Swift** chamado **Playground**. Nele você pode digitar quase qualquer código em **Swift** e ver detalhes sobre a sua execução fácil e rapidamente.
Costumo utilizá-lo muito para testar códigos que não envolvam a parte de Interface Gráfica

Para abrir o **Playground**:

1. Abra o XCode
2. Clique em `File > New > Playground`
3. Dê um nome para o arquivo
4. Comece a digitar seu código